# Android Studio "Error Running Git" , 'Empty git --version output:'

Tags: android, git, version-control, android-studio-2.2

I have looked at the other posts and have made certain that the path is correct to the executable file, as shown below.  I can launch git from from this path outside of Android Studio.  The current project is the "sunshine-version 2" from Udacity and it is a version or two old, but this should not affect the VCS from launching.  I have read the other posts concerning this issue, but none have resolved this issue.
[image]
Also, when Android Studio gradle runs, it will open git in several windows and then close them almost immediately.  They pop-up for a second or two, and then close.  It's definitely trying to run git, and then default closes?

Comment: Also, when I click on "Test" , a scroll bar pops up, but spins its wheels endlessly.  There is no result, but an unending 'check' if you will...

Comment: Can you execute this from a command prompt? Also, you have a git path set, but also have _Built-in_ selected.

Comment: I changed it from 'built-in' to the only other option...'Native' and the same error occured.

Comment: `Native` would be the path specified. It is strange that built-in would give the same error. Can you try Built-in without a path specified? Can you execute this from a command prompt?

Comment: yes, from the 'native' or from the 'built-in' options, it is throwing the Empty git --version output response, when I click the "Test" button.  I can launch this executable file from the command line.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I just went to the Git path ubication, the only different thing that I did was have stopped at the cmd folder. As you might see in the next screenshot

[image]

Subsequently, instead of choosing git-gui.exe option, I select just git.exe option. And it seems to work for me.

[image]

Comment: this one helped me a lot

Comment: This one helped me as well. I had to change the path to executable to 'bin/git.exe'

Answer (score 10):

default path of git.exe for GitHubDesktop 64-bit version is

```
c:\Users\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-<version>\resources\app\git\cmd\git.exe
```

you should try this path.

Answer (score 8):

in windows 10, 64bit version your installed git location is **C:\Program Files\Git**, There is a **bin** folder inside **Git** folder and there is a **git.exe** file, this is the file you have to choose or add in android studio.Works for me.

Answer (score 4):

The path you configure for git should be `C:\Users\Computer\Documents\Development\Git\cmd\git.exe` instead. You should use `git.exe` not `git-base.exe`.

And add git installed path to environment variables (for windows OS):

This PC -> properties -> Advanced system setting -> advanced Tab -> environment variables -> find path in **system variables** -> edit -> add the git installed path  by `;C:\Users\Computer\Documents\Development\Git\cmd` -> ok.

Comment: I tried 'git.exe' but it said no such file.  I double checked the path and it is definitely to the right executable file.

Comment: Which version do you use for git? Or you can download the newest version in https://git-scm.com/downloads. And then use the new install path `...\Git\cmd\git.exe`.

Comment: I am using the latest version of git.  Also, I have GitHub set as version control for the current project.  It has no problem connecting when I click on 'Test', but I would like to use git locally, and then push/pull to GitHub.  For some reason it keeps throwing this Empty version output message.  I have even deleted the entire studio, and git, and reinstalled both.  Not sure where the bug is ?  Could there be some setting withiin git that I need to alter...?  What's funny is when I browse to the uninstall_git.exe and click on 'Test' , it actually launches the uninstaller for git ?

Comment: Did you add `C:\Users\Computer\Documents\Development\Git\cmd` in your environment variables?

Comment: I do not know what that is or how to do that...please guide me in this.

Comment: Yes, I added the method to add environment variables in my answer.

Comment: Did the answer you help solve the problem? If yes, please mark it. And it will help others who have similar question.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Marina-MSFT, you should add git.exe instead of git-base.exe or any other .exe files. You could find git.exe under, in your case, C:\Users\Computer\Documents\Development\Git\bin\git.exe, normally the git.exe file is under bin file of Git you have installed

Answer (score 1):

You should give a path in git.exe in cmd folder

Try this: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe

Answer (score 0):

This is the path where GitHub is located in its default installation.
Remove the text including "<>" characters in below path and enter your relevant values.

```
c:\Users\<Your Windows username>\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-<version>\resources\app\git\cmd\git.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

For x64-bit Windows version change the path directory to

```
Android Studio:  File > Settings... > Version Control > Git

c:\Users\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-<version>\resources\app\git\cmd\git.exe
```

Change default settings on Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

you should go into the "cmd" folder which is created in the main folder that you've installed the Git program. (usually is C:\Program Files\Git). In this folder you can find Git.exe then copy this address in configuration windows in Android Studio.