# Error running git

Tags: git, github

**Error-** 
`Cannot run program "git.exe":CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

I have been looking on forums for a good 2 hours now and every forum is from a couple of years ago, which advises to change the path to git executable, but i'm guessing after an update this has disappeared from the settings and I am unable to set the correct path.

I know this was probably quite vague but hope you guys can help as I swift kick through my computer screen is only a matter of time.

Comment: have you installed [gitbash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/)? what OS you are running on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git.exe` ... so Windows?

1. Narrow things down. From outside of Android Studio, from a Command Window, if you type `git`, does it return a help list of git commands, or does it also not find git?
2. If it doesn’t find git, are sure you installed it? Do you know where it is? Can you identify the location of the git executable?
3. If so, then the path variable you want to set is the system `Path` environment variable. Hit the Windows button to open the Windows menu, and search for *system environment variable*. Follow the menu options to edit the `Path` variable, and then add a program path. Then type in or copy/paste the git path. Now, when you try to run git from command line (Command Window), Windows will know where to look to find git.
4. This may resolve the issue within Android Studio as well, but if not then there is likely a setting menu within that application to help it find git as well.

Comment: @Joe.grove63 Glad to help! Upvote, mark as correct, if you will!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that, in the `Android studio settings / Version Control / Git`, you have entered the PATH of `git.exe` [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42124682/6309).

You can simply download the [latest Git for Widows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), like [`PortableGit-2.18.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.18.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.18.0-64-bit.7z.exe), uncompress anywhere you want (`C:\git` for instance), and put: `C:\git\bin\git.exe`.